# Is there a technical name and rules for a double-touch in badminton?

Tags: rules, terminology, badminton

Double-touch (at least that's what people call at my court) is when the shuttle touches the racket more than once in an instance.

So, what are the rules regarding this?  Does the point count?

If not, then is the point awarded to the opponent or is the rally abandoned?

Is there a technical/official term for "double touch" in Badminton?

Comment: The common phrase is [double hit](http://www.worldbadminton.com/glossary.htm#Double_Hit) but it's not in the official rules AFAIK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rules of Badminton state:

> 13. FAULTS:  It shall be a ‘fault’:
>
> ...
>
> 13.3 if in play, the shuttle:
>
> ...
>
> 13.3.6 is caught and held on the racket and then slung during the execution of a stroke;
>
> 13.3.7 is hit twice in succession by the same player. However, a shuttle hitting the head and the stringed area of the racket in one stroke shall not be a ‘fault’;
>
> 13.3.8 is hit by a player and the player’s partner successively;

Source: http://www.bwfbadminton.org/file.aspx?id=680849&dl=1

So to answer your questions:

> So, what are the rules regarding this? Does the point count?

The point counts. But it is a fault. Hence, the point is awarded to your opponent. See 13.3.8. However, be award that if the shuttle first hits the head and then the stringed area, it is NOT a fault and therefore a legal shot.

> If not, then is the point awarded to the opponent or is the rally abandoned?

See above.

> Is there a technical/official term for "double touch" in Badminton?

When looking at the official rules, it seems, there is no official term.